# Plotly bar chart - change color based on positive/negative value - python

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code which plots a bar chart (1 series), but I need the bars to be coloured blue if the 'Net' value is positive, and red if its negative:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Net':[15,20,-10,-15], 
     'Date':['07/14/2020','07/15/2020','07/16/2020','07/17/2020']
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(name='Net', x=df['Date'], y=df['Net'])])
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think that you can use [candlestick](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) here. You can eventually use custom colors following [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/#custom-candlestick-colors)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#colored-and-styled-bar-chart). Full code as following

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Data

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Net':[15,20,-10,-15], 
     'Date':['07/14/2020','07/15/2020','07/16/2020','07/17/2020']
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

## here I'm adding a column with colors
df["Color"] = np.where(df["Net"]<0, 'red', 'green')

# Plot
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(name='Net',
           x=df['Date'],
           y=df['Net'],
           marker_color=df['Color']))
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly and you should give yourself some more credit: I wouldn't have extracted this from the documentation. The `np.where()` mapping approach is great.

Answer (score 3):

@rpanai that is a great answer and got me where I needed to go. I wanted to simply add a way to do the same if using `plotly.express`.

Note that most of this is the *same* as above.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Net':[15,20,-10,-15],
       'Date':['07/14/2020','07/15/2020','07/16/2020','07/17/2020']
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df["Color"] = np.where(df["Net"]<0, 'red', 'green')

# PLOT
fig = px.bar(df,x="Date",y="Net")

# COLOR
fig.update_traces(marker_color=df["Color"])

fig.show()
```